# How to validate coupons in Magento 2 without the need for customerids

Tags: php, magento2

I'm a bit new here so please correct me if I'm being dumb.

I've imported about 5 million coupon codes into Magento 2 and everything is working quite fast except for the communication with the table ''salesrule_customer''.

So I thought I'd just get rid if the need to validate customerid and always have all customerids valid for all cart rules.

And here's where I need some help. I can't seem to find the area for sure where this validation happens. So I don't know what to override in my module.

I've been dabbeling around a bit in: Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule

But I'm honestly quite lost.

Anyone in here who has done this before or know how to do this?

I think the following code might be the culprit:

```
/**
     * Limit rules collection by specific customer group
     *
     * @param int $customerGroupId
     * @return $this
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    public function addCustomerGroupFilter($customerGroupId)
    {
        $entityInfo = $this->_getAssociatedEntityInfo('customer_group');
        if (!$this->getFlag('is_customer_group_joined')) {
            $this->setFlag('is_customer_group_joined', true);
            $this->getSelect()->join(
                ['customer_group' => $this->getTable($entityInfo['associations_table'])],
                $this->getConnection()
                    ->quoteInto('customer_group.' . $entityInfo['entity_id_field'] . ' = ?', $customerGroupId)
                . ' AND main_table.' . $entityInfo['rule_id_field'] . ' = customer_group.'
                . $entityInfo['rule_id_field'],
                []
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

I might also be completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

check the method **canProcessRule** from file *vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Utility.php*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).